# An app like WhatsApp for Windows and Android with separate users

Tags: whatsapp

I need an app like WhatsApp that I can install it on Windows with a different user than the one on the phone, so I can send messages between phone and PC.

What I am looking for is to find the easiest way to send text messages from the phone to the PC. Using Gmail is not really quick and easy

Comment: Take a look at [XMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP) clients for example. For Android this would be [Conversations](https://f-droid.org/packages/eu.siacs.conversations/), for the PC most likely [Gajim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gajim) which is available cross-platform.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very good idea. I am using Xabber on the phone (Conversations asks for money) and Gajim on the Windows PC. Please add your comment in an actual answer so I will vote and accept it.

Comment: I tried Skype and it works even better. For some reason, Xabber doesn't make a sound when you get a new message, unless you are in the Xabber application. Even though the notifications are turned on. OTOH, Skype makes the notification sound all the time - even if the application is not started (not running in background)

Comment: "Conversations asks for money": guess you're using the wrong store then. It never asked me for money. Sure you installed it from F-Droid, as linked by me? And yes, it makes a sound (I had to silence some channels as it got too much LOL). I'd never use any proprietary messaging system – especially not from a data collecting company like MS, Google & Co, so Skype would be out for me.